# Add to cart in custom page with custom field

Tags: php, magento, cart

can i set custom value in cart add product

i create field ref_order_id in sales_flat_quote_item to save data if is product add to cart with my custom page

but product with save to cart with qty but ref_order_id is not insert into database

How i can save this value into database

it my code

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');


$cart->init();


$cart->addProduct($product, array('qty' => $qty), array('ref_order_id' => $ref_order_id));


$cart->save();


Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

Comment: try this $cart->addProduct($product, array('qty' => $qty,'ref_order_id' => $ref_order_id));

Comment: is not working in sales_flat_quote_item.ref_order_id is stay null